# Combine output of for loop to variable

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have a question regarding the for loop in bash.

I want to write a script which is looping through the directory of each cpanel user and looks for a certain file. I only want to loop through the folders of cpanel users and not of other folders within the /home directory.

This is what i got so far:

```
cd /var/cpanel/users
for user in *
do
    find /home/$user -type f -name "*myfile*" 
done

mail -s "the results" my@email.com $MYOUTPUT
```

What i dont understand is, how I can collect all the output from the for..do..done loop and store it in one variable which i can send via email ($MYOUTPUT)

I was thinking doing it like this:

```
MYOUTPUT = ""
cd /var/cpanel/users

for user in *
do
    WHAT=$(find /home/$user -type f -name "*myfile*")
        $MYOUTPUT = $MYOUTPUT$WHAT
done


mail -s "result" my@email.com $MYOUTPUT
```

But that doesnt work.. Any ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: FYI assignments cannot have spaces around the `=`. You have to write `MYOUTPUT=""` not `MYOUTPUT = ""`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: To assign something to a variable, you have to

1. Use the variable name without the `$` before the `=` sign.
2. not have any spaces surrounding the `=` character.

So what you'd need is something like this:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    myvar="$myvar $i"
done
echo $myvar
```

Secondly, you can just redirect the whole output into a variable:

```
myvar=$(for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done)
echo $myvar
```

Answer (score 4):

`mail` will read from stdin. You can pipe the output of the loop to it without any temporary variables.

```
for user in *
do
    find /home/$user -type f -name "*myfile*" 
done | mail -s "the results" my@email.com
```

You could even get rid of the loop by having a single `find` command search all of the directories.

```
find /home/* -type f -name "*myfile*" | mail -s "the results" my@email.com
```

Actually, the `*` isn't necessary.

```
find /home -type f -name "*myfile*" | mail -s "the results" my@email.com
```

Comment: *... isn't necessary.* ... this is not exactly true. Assuming that you have a file `/home/.myfile` (which is unlikely, but possible), `find /home` would find it, but `find /home/*` would not.